# Water spilled over LCD screen, small and growing black dot portion appears on the bottom of the screen

Tags: display, lcd

Yesterday I accidentally spilled some water over my 22 inch LCD Dell Monitor’s Screen and after 15 minutes I saw small black portion at the mid bottom of my screen and it keeps on expanding.

What should I do now? What can be done to get my LCD screen back to normal?

Comment: You pretty much have to wait (and hope) for it to dry. Sunlight might help. It will spread for a while as the water wicks upwards, and may take quite a while - last time this happened to me it took several weeks. Incidentally, it's just an LCD screen - LED refers to the backlighting, and is irrelevant to this issue.

Comment: So should I turn it on or what ?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After the water spill, I'd immediately turn off the monitor and give it a sufficient time to dry.  Continuing to use the thing with water present in the electronics will no doubt be problematic for the monitor and could be permanent.

Comment: How much time would be sufficient in such case, in my case only a small portion is turn black and I immediately turned it off. it has  been 1 day since I turned it off.